# Remove the end of an url using php

Tags: php, trim

I have got this URL:

`http://website.com/theimage.jpg?sw=536&sh=536&sm=fit`

I want to end it at before the `sw` ending varies, though.

How can I do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: So what you're saying is you want to output that image without the query string being printed with it. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: there are a lot of people looking for answer only for downgrade the vote, use result=strtok($url,'?');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried php's function explode?
[PHP: explode- Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

You would need something like:

```
$url = "http://website.com/theimage.jpg?sw=536&sh=536&sm=fit";  
$pieces= explode("?", $url);  
$cleanurl = $pieces[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$url='http://website.com/theimage.jpg?sw=536&sh=536&sm=fit';
$urlNew=strtok($url,'?');
```

the result

```
==> $urlNew='http: //website.com/theimage.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `explode` to break a string in pieces

```
    $url = "http://website.com/theimage.jpg?sw=536&sh=536&sm=fit";
    $pieces = explode("?", $url);
    echo $pieces[0];
    echo $pieces[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use explode function to split a string.

```
$url= "http://website.com/theimage.jpg?sw=536&sh=536&sm=fit";
$urlArray = explode("sw", $pizza);
echo $urlArray[0]; // http://website.com/theimage.jpg?
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can just go with parse_url

```
$url = 'http://website.com/theimage.jpg?sw=536&sh=536&sm=fit';
print_r(parse_url($url));
```

result

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => website.com
    [path] => /theimage.jpg
    [query] => sw=536&sh=536&sm=fit
)
```